# How to change http user/group in ec2 rmi user/data script?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to configure an ec2 as my web server that will scale out under a load balancer, but as the httpd.conf comments say,

```
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User apache
Group apache
```

The default user and group for a  standard Amazon Linux RMI are apache. I would like to change this to a user and group I have created, say, my-user.

As you'll know, the User/Data section of an ec2 can contain a bash script that will perform actions when the ec2 is provisioned. I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum install httpd24 mysql57 php71 php71-mysql\* -y
```

Is it possible to use CLI commands to change the httpd user and group from this bash script after installing httpd - or use environment variables in the httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found this worked  for me:

```
# configure the httpd web server daemon to run as user ddfs
touch /etc/httpd/conf.d/ddfs.conf
chmod 777 /etc/httpd/conf.d/ddfs.conf 
cat <<EOF > /etc/httpd/conf.d/ddfs.conf
User ddfs
Group ddfs
EOF
chmod 644 /etc/httpd/conf.d/ddfs.conf
# start the web server daemon
service httpd start
# Set the server config so that httpd automatically gets started when the server is booted
chkconfig httpd on
```